# Input to an array of pointers from a file showing error

Tags: c, file, csv, runtime-error, structure

I am facing this error "subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector" for the `empF[i]`
here is my code

```
employee empF[100];
int i=0;
void test(){
    FILE *fp;
    employee empF;
    fp=fopen("employee.csv","r");
    employee temp;
    char x[100];
    while(fgets(x,100,fp)!=NULL){
        removeCommas(x);
        sscanf(x,"%d %s %ld %s %d",&(temp.employee_id),temp.employee_name,&(temp.phno),temp.shift,&(temp.area_code));
        empF[i].employee_id=temp.employee_id;
        empF[i].employee_name=temp.employee_name;
        empF[i].phno=temp.phno;
        empF[i].shift=temp.shift;
        empF[i].area_code=temp.area_code;
        i+=1;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

here is the employee struct

```
typedef struct employee
{
    int employee_id;
    char employee_name[20];
    long int  phno;
    char shift[10];
    int area_code;
}employee;
```

It seems to run just fine if I don't use an array of structs. What exactly I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You redefined the variable name `empF` in the function, and declared with `employee` (non-array) type.

```c
void test(){
    FILE* fp;
    employee empF; /* <-- here */
    /* ... */
}
```

So when you're referencing `empF`, you're referencing the non-array local variable inside the function.

Comment: oh, that's my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot removing

> employee empF;

line when you switched from one employee to many. This declaration overrides previous array declaration.

(Also, you don't actually need `temp` employee; you can directly scan to `empF[i]` but you may have your reasons :))

Comment: Got it. My bad.